# Seeking CBIR help. Trying to pull images from database that are most similar (texture based) to selected image

Tags: java, image, image-processing, textures

I am trying to create a content based image retrieval system. I can currently click a button on my GUI that will upload an image from my file explorer. I can also select the path of the images I want to compare the selected image against with another button. I have then created a third button called 'texture'. On click, I want this button to pull the most similar images from the selected path based on my selected image I initially uploaded.

My problem is, I don't know where to start with regards to pulling the relevant images. I have tried using LIRE and Catalano but both have minimal if any documentation to help me and I am not experienced using libraries and my Java is just ok.

```
//Texture Method
public void compareTexture(File user, File base) { 
 System.out.println("Comparing texture: " + user.getName() + " VS " + base.getName()); 
}
```

as you can see, I can pull images from file explorer no problem. I just have a real lack of understanding on how to retrieve similar images based on texture. Any ideas of where to start or good resources to help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Most similar in what sense?  Image recognition is a [hard](http://xkcd.com/1425/) problem. For instance, a naive pixel comparison is fairly easy to implement, but doesn't usually match what people think of as "similar".

Comment: @azurefrog Well basically I want to extract the details of the image. I have said texture, but it could be edge or anything. So lets say, i have selected an image of a cat, I would want the results of my query to show other cats.  How do I do that using say, edge detection? I know in my op I said texture, but could be anything. I dont know where to start, and would ideally like to start at the most basic of feature extraction methods. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, here's a [list of CIBR engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CBIR_engines).  But keep in mind that the "research team and five years" bit in the xkcd I linked to is not really that much of an exaggeration.  Figuring out that there is a cat in your image is not trivial.